# Where does an "adapter" fit in MVP (passive view)?

Tags: java, android, swing

I have been implementing my android app with what I think is Passive MVP.

So for example in my view class I have a ListView.

### View

```
ListView userListView;
```

and when an item is clicked, i simpley call a method on the presenter

```
userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mPresenter.onUserSelected(position);

    }

});
```

The part that I am confused about is that a ListView requires an adapter.

### Presenter

So currently in my presenter I have this:

```
private ArrayList<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

...

```
adapter = new UserListAdapter(getContext(), mUserList);
mView.setUserListAdapter(adapter);
```

and when I want to change something I do this:

```
mUserList.add(user);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is this the right place to the adapter?  The reason I ask is because I was recently looking to do some work with swing, and a similar issue arises, JLists need a ListModel which seems pretty similar.  So for swing, where would should the ListModel reside?

Comment: You may be looking for the [_adapter pattern_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), often required to match an existing component model to an application model.

Comment: no, the question is more related to the MVP pattern.  It seems like in mvp I should just be telling the view to update some a widget with new data, but since in this case the widget needs an adapter, I am not sure if the adapter belongs in the view or the presenter.  I am not sure it really matters, but it's gnawing at my brain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've correctly categorized your adapter as a Presenter.

The Presenter IS the adapter.

The adapter serves as the middle-man between the View (ListView) and Model (your List of Users) and provides View representations of each of the items in the List via the adapter's getView method.

Comment: let me give it a day or so to see if I get any other thoughts, otherwise I will accept your answer.   Kind of a freebie :)

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know the adapter is also a view and it might have a presenter to work with as well.

Answer (score 0):

In MVP pattern, the view layer should contains all platform dependencies. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858153/2502464).

To deal with the adapter abstraction you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32462572/2502464).